Rust - как указать в http-запросе пользовательский метод LIST?
Использую reqwest для выполнения запроса.
Вот такой запрос в curl:
curl --request POST --data '{"role_id":"222","secret_id":"444"}' https://vault.main.ru/v1/auth/approle/login

Будет выглядеть и работает вот так:
let url_login = "https://vault.main.ru/v1/auth/approle/login";
let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    
    let json_data = r#"{"role_id":"222","secret_id":"444"}"#;
    let response = client
        .post(url_login)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body(json_data.to_owned())
        .send()
        .await?;

А как через reqwest выполнить вот такой запрос curl?
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: sdf33422323" --request LIST https://vault.main.ru/v1/secretsstream/metadata

LIST - насколько я понял, это пользовательский метод. Как его передавать?

В крайнем случае всё ещё есть GET https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/4991

это конечно хорошо, что еще get работает у них, но все таки как -то он же должен передаваться в запросе . Чисто теоретически даже интересно.

А вообще всегда можно поковырять исходники: Client::post ведёт в Client::request, который принимает подозрительный объект Method, в котором есть подозрительный метод from_bytes, в который наверно можно попытаться запихнуть b"LIST" (но это не точно, не пробовал)

Да, заработало вот так:
let client = Client::new();    
let url = "https://test.com/1.php";
let json_data = r#"{"role_id":"48ef7b9e","secret_id":"23e8c3de"}"#;
let req = client.request(Method::from_bytes(b"LIST").unwrap(), url).body(json_data.to_owned());
let response = req.send().await?;

